# Should I also pass class member data as references for speed?

Tags: c++, reference

I understand that passing an object by reference can significantly increase speed as it avoids calling unnecessary constructors when in comparison we pass by mere value.

1) Does it make sense to have references or pointers to trivial member data within a class, e.g. int& some_int or int* p_int in some Class Foo?

2) In particular, if I want to create all class object on the Free Store anyway, does declaring a class member like int* p_int make sense in terms of any memory gain?

Thx

Comment: No, this makes no sense at all.

Comment: just as I thought.. it only time I needed a pointer to some int is when I needed to manipulate dynamic member data of another class. I use references for object members within a class though.

Comment: Pass by reference in function arguments avoids a copy which can make it faster. In your examples you are not avoiding anything, but in fact only creating additional complexity. Refs/pointers in a class can make sense if instances have to share access to something or for dynamic/temporary data and some other cases, but not here.

Comment: @user2802841: you mean I should try to have all my member functions taking references, say double Foo::Poo(int & some_int) ?

Comment: @user2856452 This depends, for small types like int/float probably no point. But for larger structs/classes like std::vector, std::string or your own classes that contain more then few members you should use const references where possible.

Comment: yes, that's what I did.. I used all my std::string as references, all objects. Didn't think you can pass a whole vector by reference, but I haven't made use of passing vectors yet. Thans.

Comment: @user2802841 No, actually.  As long as you don't trigger a deep-copy, passing by value on some structs is actual better.  [See this blog post](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)

Comment: ohh that's interesting.. as I have large vectors of objects and wanted to play around soon enough..

Comment: @SamCristall But that is more advanced topic and is very implementation specific.

Comment: I am in the process of optimizing my graphics engine. What Sam Cristall says is what I needed - exceptions to the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest method is to pass values by copy *if they fit within the processor's register*.  The compiler will load the processor's registers then call the function.

For larger data, there may be no speed difference between passing by reference and passing by pointer.  In either case, the pointers and references must be deferenced before they can be used, thus taking extra instructions.

Also, one case to measure is to pass structures by copy to the function.  This would involve three operations:  copy variables to stack, increment stack size, at the receiving side:  copying variables from the stack.

The objective to increasing performance is to design the functions to use registers and reduce the amount of loading and storing to memory.

For example, on an ARM7 loading a register from a variable in memory:

- Load a register with the address of the variable.
- Load another register by deferencing the register with the address.
  Some processors can load from memory directly by embedding the address within the instruction.

Before coding in the manner, profile your correct and robust code to find the performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

At the implementation level references are just pointers with syntactic sugar. Pointer, of course, require memory, usually it takes 4 (for x86) or 8 bytes (x64, there could be other cases) per ptr. **Thus, having pointers for primitives could result in memory vasting.**

Also, dereferencing pointer takes some time. Basically, you get value of a pointer, go to that address and get the desired value. Here you see 2 memory reads (which could be pretty distant, by the way, which is bad for CPU caching) instead of 1 in case of working with primitive. **So pointers could lead to time performance degradation** (though, I think, you'll never face it cause it's very insignificant).

Still, pointers (or references) for primitives could be useful if you want to share it between several places. But it's rare case.

Answer (score 0):

I have found initializer lists to be helpful for performance.